# Requests From Windows Azure Are blocked for a certain server

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, azure-web-roles

I have (2 Websites, 1 Worker Role, 1 Web Role) all of them hosted on Azure, all of these are different installations that have a copy of the same code that initiates a WebHttpRequest to a web service, and they have been working for months, suddenly requests to the web service are failing, My local versions are working fine.

Windows Azure must be blocking all my outgoing requests to this specific webservice, anyone knows Why ? and how i can fix this?

My diagnose steps
1. Tracert for the webservice host fails
2. opening the webservice through browser fails
3. checking requests on the hosting server, no requests are reaching from my azure

All the above succeed for requests outside azure.

The Exception im getting

System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection

failed because connected host has failed to respond XX.XX.XX.XX:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Answer (score 0):

Okay we found out the issue, hope it will be helpful to anyone who faces such a thing.
Websites in Azure have a shared IP Address, thus what happened is, there was another website that falls under the same IP that was black listed on a couple of DNS boxes, thus requests in & out our website were unstable and most of the time blocked.
If you face a similar issue just check if your website is black listed, it might by because of your website or any other website on the box.

Comment: Where did you validate if your website is black listed? We are having the same issue here, but we are having a static IP as we are using a IP Based SSL certificate.